# Convert from CAD file DWG to geodatabase features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, feature-class, cad

How can I convert CAD file with different layers to specific feature classes for ex. Layers 2000 , 2001 ,2002 I want to convert them together to a polygon feature class  with name buildings , and convert layers 2003 , 2004 together to another feature class with name parcels?

[image]

Comment: you can open you dwg file in ArcGIS Catalog and right click in cad layer and then export them as feature class or shapefile, if you are using ArcGIS pro this link would be helpful https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/conversion/cad-to-geodatabase.htm  or https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/using-the-cad-to-geodatabase-tool.htm

Comment: Thank you for your quieck answer , but i do not want just to convert from cad to gis i want to convert groups of different layers in autocad to different feature classes in gis